# Forçar uma classe ter um atributo

Tags: c++, orientação-a-objetos

Estou fazendo um projeto e preciso que uma classe pai (herança) force as suas classes filhas ter um certo atributo. É possível fazer isso?

Comment: Se a classe mãe possuir um atributo, todas as filhas possuirão. Não ficou clara a sua dúvida.

Comment: Pq existe um método que todas as classes filhas tem que executar no momento de sua criação, e essa função necessita de um atributo que ele deve clonar de um protótipo. Queria garantir que ele forçe as filhas a buscar esse atributo.

Comment: No construtor? Basta chamar o da classe pai ao criar o construtor (`public SubClass(int param) : SuperClass(int param) { ... }`)